# Get XTick locations and display text near them

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

**My goal:** use `text` command to put text near an `xtick`, but *not via* `xticklabel`.

**Example:**
Suppose I have the following code

```
figure
plot([1:10],[1:10])
set(gca, 'XTick',[3])
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',{''})
```

Now, I would like to write something like (this is not a working code)

```
ticklocs = get(gca,'xtick',locations);
text(locations(1),locations(2), 'my cool text here');
```

I know that that I can put the text in the `XTickLabel` format, but it does not enable me all the text flexibility that `text` allows me.

*If you do* know how to put Latex in the `xticklabel`, it is also interesting, but an off topic for this post (just comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `xtick` property which will give you the x value of the tick mark. You can then use the axes `ylim` property to determine the minimum `y` value which will be it's rough `y` location. You can then apply padding as necessary to these values and use `text` to display text wherever.

```
ax = axes();

% Get the upper and lower y limits
ylims = get(ax, 'ylim');

% Get the x positions of the tick marks
xticks = get(ax, 'xtick');

% For each tick we're going to use padding between -10% of the ylimits to 10%
padding = linspace(-0.1, 0.1, numel(xticks));

for k = 1:numel(padding)
    % Compute the y value based upon the desired padding and the lower y limit
    yvalue = ylims(1) - diff(ylims) * padding(k);

    % Display the text
    text(xticks(k), yvalue, sprintf('Label %d', k), 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
    hold on
end
```

[image]

That being said, since R2015a, you can put LaTeX directly in your xtick labels and use the [`TickLabelInterpreter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_TickLabelInterpreter) property of the `axes` to specify that you'd like to use the LaTeX interpreter.

```
axes('Xtick', [0 0.5 1], ...
     'XTickLabel', {'10\circ', 'x^{1}', 'Y_2'}, ...
     'TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex')
```

[image]

Comment: You can get the exact Y location of the ticks using undocumented features, e.g. (R2015b): `ax.XRuler.MajorTickChild.VertexData`.  This returns a **2*NTicks x 3** matrix detailing the start and end positions of each of the ticks in X, Y and Z.